# using pySerial to get device data through RS485

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-2.7, pyserial

I want to get device data from RS485 serial port,

use an RS485 to USB converter.

I use the same code on Windows and Linux base.

I can get data on windows,But can't get any data on Linux.

Why...? I use the same code...

Only different Windows port is 'COM7',
and Linux port is '/dev/ttyUSB0'

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import serial
import binascii
import time

ser = serial.Serial()

def initSerial():
    global ser
    ser.baudrate = 9600
    #ser.port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
    ser.port = 'COM7'
    #ser.timeout =0
    ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
    ser.bytesize = 8
    ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
    ser.rtscts = 0

def main():
    initSerial()
    global ser
    ser.open()
    while True:
        mHex = ser.read()
        if len(mHex)!= 0:
            print("get",binascii.hexlify(bytearray(mHex)))
        time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and windows can get data like this:

```
('get', '01')
('get', 'ab')
('get', 'ba')
('get', '01')
('get', '01')
```

Comment: Does it not give any data, or give you an error?

Comment: on Linux, no any data response, get data length is 0. no error.

Comment: Is it a full-duplex or half-duplex RS485 converter?  Also, have you tried putty or miniterm to see if you can get data?

Comment: maybe is a half-duplex RS485 converter. and I use putty can get data.

Comment: If it is half-duplex, there may be something in termios you need to do to get the send/receive set right.  I'd start by playing around with the ctl signals such as rts/dtr/dts.  (Well, actually, I'd start by ripping apart the adapter and taking a look, but that's just me...)